# Dependency Parser Not Working - Stanford Core NLP

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I've been working on a project regarding NLP and I'm using Stanford Core NLP library for it, but it's parser function doesn't seem to work. I run the code and it always gets hung up, not responding for hours.

Tried changing the way i pass directory address to the function, tried re-downloading the Stanford Core NLP files again.

```py
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
import re
import os
import itertools
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from stanfordcorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
import json

sentences = []
sents_clauses = []

def feature_extraction():
    print("Directory Access")
    os.chdir('C://Users/mohdm/Documents/FYP/stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05/')
    print("Directory Accessed")
    CORE_NLP_DIR = os.getcwd()
    print(CORE_NLP_DIR)
    print("Setting Parser")
    PARSER = StanfordCoreNLP(CORE_NLP_DIR, memory='4g', lang='en')
    print("Parser Set")
```

Actual Output:

```
Code Started
Directory Access
Directory Accessed
C:\Users\mohdm\Documents\FYP\stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05
Setting Parser
```

---

Expected Output:

```
Code Started
Directory Access
Directory Accessed
C:\Users\mohdm\Documents\FYP\stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05
Setting Parser
Parser Set
```

Comment: Did you start the CoreNLP Server (see https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html)? What is your Java version?

Comment: As the problem is that the call to `StanfordCoreNLP` is taking very long, I have to wonder: is it reasonable on your system to tell the parser that it can have 4G of memory?

Comment: @PawelKranzberg Current Java Version is 1.8.0_201, Latest

Comment: @BoarGules My Laptop Currently Has 6 Gigs of RAM. I've Tried it with 4G & 6G. But no Fruition.

Comment: I was suggesting you might need to specify *less* memory, not more. There are other processes in your computer that also need some of that memory.

Comment: See notes at https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/cmdline.html : On a 64-bit machine, Stanford CoreNLP typically requires 2GB to run (and it may need up to 6GB, depending on the annotators used and the size of the document to parse). On a 32 bit machine (in 2016, this is most commonly a 32-bit Windows machine), you cannot allocate 2GB of RAM; probably you should try with -Xmx1800m or maybe with just -Xmx1500m, but this amount of memory is a bit marginal. You probably can’t run some annotators, such as the statistical coref.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the corenlp path in `StanfordCoreNLP(CORE_NLP_DIR, memory='4g', lang='en')`, Can you make sure that Server is started?. 
It would better do it in this way. 
It will have the corenlp to point to url:

```
standfordnlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost', port=9000)
```

and run the server in command line

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000
```